# How save input from static page to database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

i want to save a input "email" from static pages to the database. Right now, i have a emails model with a :address field, but i can't save the value when click the submit input.

**Layout with form**

```
# layout/website.html.erb
<div>
  <%= form_for @email, :url => newsletter_path, :method => :post do |email| %>
    <%= email.text_field :address %>
    <%= email.submit "Go" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Pages Controller**

```
# controllers/pages_controller.rb
def home
  newsletter
end

def newsletter
  @email = Email.new(params[:address])

  if @email.valid?
    redirect_to(request.referer, :notice => "The suscription has been sent successfully.")
  else
    redirect_to(request.referer, :alert => "Please add an valid email address.")
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
# routes.rb from static pages
  get "/home" => 'pages#home', :as => :home
  get "/pricing" => 'pages#pricing', :as => :pricing
  get "/logo-gallery" => 'pages#logo_gallery', :as => :logo_gallery
  get "/blog" => 'pages#blog', :as => :blog
  get "/blog/:id" => 'pages#post', :as => :post
  get "/contact" => 'pages#contact', :as => :contact
  match '/contact' => 'pages#create', :as => :contact, :via => :post
  get "/faqs-and-terms" => 'pages#faqs_and_terms', :as => :faqs_and_terms

  match "/newsletter" => 'pages#newsletter', :as => :newsletter, :via => :post
```

**Model**

```
# models/email.rb 
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address
  validates :address, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true
end
```

With this code, when visit /home right now i'm received:

```
ActionController::ActionControllerError in PagesController#home
Cannot redirect to nil!
```

I hope you can help me, what can i do to fix this and get a better code. Thank you.

Comment: You could try `redirect_to :back`

Comment: Means you want to save value in DB or want to redirect?

Comment: @harsh4u save valui in DB, and then redirect to the same page with the notice or if is invalid, with the alert.

Comment: @hedgesky if i used :back i received the message... No HTTP_REFERER was set in the request to this action, so redirect_to :back could not be called successfully. If this is a test, make sure to specify request.env["HTTP_REFERER"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newsletter action email record is only initialized but not saved. And you have no need to call newsletter method inside home action every time. Just update your code like this.

**Pages Controller**

```
# controllers/pages_controller.rb
.....
# no need to call newsletter action here
def home      
end

def newsletter
  @email = Email.new(params[:email])

  if @email.save
    redirect_to((request.referer || '/'), :notice => "The suscription has been sent successfully.")
  else
    redirect_to((request.referer || '/'), :alert => "Please add an valid email address.")
  end
end
```

**Layout with form**

As @email is not defined in controller, so you should initialize an Email object in form.

```
# layout/website.html.erb
<div>
  <%= form_for Email.new, :url => newsletter_path, :method => :post do |email| %>
    <%= email.text_field :address %>
    <%= email.submit "Go" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I hope that it should work.

Comment: this generate:    Started GET "/home" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Sep 05 00:32:46 -0700 2013
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "emails" ("address", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["address", nil], ["created_at", Thu, 05 Sep 2013 07:32:46 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Thu, 05 Sep 2013 07:32:46 UTC +00:00]]
   (20.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/home
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 20.6ms)

Comment: so did this solve your problem, where u want to redirect request after saving email record in database?

Comment: I think my problem is when i try to load the /home the form try to send the input to database, and is nil.

Comment: why you are calling newsletter method inside home action? Just remove this and try again.

Comment: if i do this, hace conflict with this :url => newsletter_path, with the error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: It is because, u have not defined @email variable. Use this in your form: <%= form_for Email.new, :url => newsletter_path, :method => :post do |email| %>

Comment: @Stanmx: have u tried the code. i think this will solve ur all problems.

Comment: ... PagesController#newsletter as HTML 
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Go", "referer"=>"value/home", "email"=>{"address"=>"me@email.com"}, "authenticity_token"=>"Sf9VC7gZgzP6vmBG52c+H/SUvZ+JPe9ZwaPXS9YIu9o="} 
(0.1ms) begin transaction 
SQL (0.5ms) INSERT INTO "emails" ("address", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?) [["address", nil], ["created_at", Thu, 05 Sep 2013 08:06:10 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Thu, 05 Sep 2013 08:06:10 UTC +00:00]] 
(8.6ms) commit transaction 
(0.1ms) begin transaction 
(0.0ms) commit transaction 
Redirected to localhost:3000value/home

Comment: when i load /home the successfully message appears and when i add my email redirect to /newsletter and appear the up message in the log.
and the email is not save in the db

Comment: i try it and appears the up 2 messages.

Comment: Use redirect_to((request.referer || '/'), :notice => "The suscription has been sent successfully."). It should work now for all cases.

Comment: @Aman_Garg is save in db, but still now validate if the field is empty, save the empty space and show the succesfully message.

Comment: I just change the validate for validates_presence_of and works. Thanks @Aman and the others for your help and time.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Email.create(params[:email])` instead of `Email.new(params[:address])` to persist records in DB. Also, in your view you code add hidden_field

```
<%= email.text_field :address %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :referer, :value => request.path %>
<%= email.submit "Go" %>
```

And then in controller:

```
redirect_to params[:referer]
```

**UPD**
Also, please notice that you should use `params[:email]` in your controller, not `params[:address]`. You can invoke `raise params.inspect` in your controller to inspect params sent by form.

Comment: I changed but still with the Cannot redirect to nil!

Comment: thank you, i make the changes you mentioned, but still with this Cannot redirect to nil!

Comment: I think the error is when i try to load /home, automatic try to create the email Started GET "/home" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Sep 05 00:35:19 -0700 2013
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "emails" ("address", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["address", nil], ["created_at", Thu, 05 Sep 2013 07:35:19 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Thu, 05 Sep 2013 07:35:19 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.9ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

Comment: This error appears because you invoke `newsletter` method in your `home` action. You should remove that line.